# How can 'arrange' command be used to generate a set of bins for histogram plot in R

Tags: r, histogram, bins

While I try to plot histogram in R by defining a set of bins I get this error 'some 'x' not counted; maybe 'breaks' do not span range of 'x''. 
I am following the information on the website 'http://msenux.redwoods.edu/math/R/hist.php' which states 'Use the arange command to produce this set of bins'. I tried to search in the internet about how to produce suitable range of bins for my data set but in vain.

Could anyone tell me how its done? or if there is any other way.
I have tried to set the bins as

```
bins=seq(0,3,by=0.2)
```

and plot histogram as

```
hist(log10(a),col=4,breaks=bins)
```

Comment: There is no `arrange` "command" in base R. That website probably has a typo and were thinking of using the `range` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that some `log10(a)` is outside the range `[0,3]`. In that case, you can simply do something like

```
bins<-seq(min(log10(a)), max(log10(a))+1, by=0.2)
```

This ensures that all the values are *within* the bins.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your suggestion seems to be a general one; what I was looking for. By the way, why was '1' added to the maximum value?

Comment: See the documentation for `hist`: if `right = TRUE` (default), the bins do not include their maximum. Thus, to ensure that the maximum of _all_ your values can be attained, we need to enlarge the last bin somewhat (the `1` is rather randomly chosen, any small value will do).