# Histogram doesn't make the breakpoints correctly

Tags: r, histogram

I have some data on a xlsx file I had succesfully put on a frequency table and the breakspoints were configured correctly with Sturges.

```
number_observations = length(data)
classes = factor(cut(data, breaks=nclass.Sturges(data)))
tabulation = as.data.frame(table(classes))
tabulation = transform(tabulacion, cumFreq = cumsum(Freq), relative = prop.table(Freq), cumRelative = cumsum(prop.table(Freq)))

% Tabulation display
    clases      Freq   cumFreq   relative   cumRelative
1    (195,262]  xxx    xxxx      x.xxxxxxx  x.xxxxxxx
2    (262,329]  yyy    yyyy      y.yyyyyyy  y.yyyyyyy
3    (329,396]  zzz    zzzz      z.zzzzzzz  z.zzzzzzz
```

Now, I need to do a histogram with the same breakpoints, but the problem is that the histogram generated doesn't make the breakpoints correctly, meaning, first, that the maximun and minimun of the data are being presented incorrectly, and second, that the histogram has more classes than the frequency table. For case of this problem, I expect the histogram has 12 classes, but for unknown reasons for me, it makes more.

Any suggestions, and/or idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You can specify the specific break points you want as part of the `breaks` argument to `hist`:

`hist(classes, breaks=c(262, 329, ...))`

Comment: without the data and the methods for importing the xpsx file, we would only be speculating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fault for not putting attention at all to this question, so, I found a solution, partially based on this one: [How can 'arrange' command be used to generate a set of bins for histogram plot in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583262/how-can-arrange-command-be-used-to-generate-a-set-of-bins-for-histogram-plot-i), and supposing I have my data in a number vector.

The question in fact was "How to set the bins of the histogram correctly", with that the bins of the histogram will represent each one of the classes, so I worked with the minimun and maximun of the data, and the range of the classes

```
bins = seq(min(data), max(data), by=range)
```

Then giving the number of bins as an argument for the breaks of the histogram.

```
hist(data, freq=TRUE, breaks=bins)
```